# chmod: WARNING: Circular directory structure

Tags: linux, filesystems

I can't delete or change permissions in a partition.

I tried to delete some files through the command line, the result:

```
rm: cannot remove 'path-to-files' : Read-only file system
```

Next thing:

```
sudo chmod 664 -R /media/storage
chmod: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
```

How do I fix it?

This is related to the trash folder, that is where the cycle is, however `ls -al` doesn't show any symbolic links that could be doing this.

Comment: I had the luxury of wiping the partition and making a new one.

Answer (score 2):

STOP!

The read-only filesystem is a signal that the OS found something bad on your disk and changed its status.

Thus, assumming that a currently mounted disk (and is in the /etc/fstab for mounting), I'd reboot the system and let fsck fix the affected disk.

It is possible that you might lose files.  If the files are key, or if the disk is so torqued that fsck cannot work, then you'll have to restore from the backups of the area that you made (or reinstall if it is the system disk).

Good luck.

Comment: I tried `sudo fsck.vfat -r /dev/sda4`, but got `Seek to 851835878912:Invalid argument`

Comment: That is a bug that was supposed to be fixed already: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dosfstools/+bug/794943